# keys for a db table for many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Just got a basic database question I want to ask:

If I have two tables to form a many to many relationship, so then I include another table in between the two tables to stop this relationship by creating one to many relationships, does the fields in the new table I created have to be both primary key and foriegn key or should they jut be foriegn key?

E.G

Course Table:

```
CourseId (PK auto)  CourseNo  CourseName
1                   2343      ICT
2                   4030      Maths
```

Course_Module Table: (This is the table I am asking if should be both PK and FK):

```
CourseId (FK course)  ModuleId (FK Module)
1                     3
1                     2
2                     1
2                     2
```

Module Table:

```
ModuleId (PK auto)  ModuleNo  ModuleName
1                   344       Algebra
2                   223       Statistics
3                   303       Systems Stratergy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would have to be composite PK (i.e. both courseId and ModuleId) as well as foreign keys because you need the combination of courseId and ModuleId to be unique and you also want referential integrity

Comment: Thanks for your answer, straight to the point which I like :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually they are both. In your case `CourseId` and `ModuleId` should form a composite primary key in the `Course_Module` table, while still being used individually as foreign keys. The sample data you provided has unique rows in that table, which is the deciding point for me.

Comment: So as you mentioned they should be composite keys, your answer is stating that the fields should include primary keys as well as the foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, @manixman. Sorry for not being clear on that. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to specify a primary on every table. There may however be a performance impact, so in this case I would recommend that you do specify a primary key as both fields.

Also note that you don't have to specify the fields as foreign keys and on some engines for MySQL, you actually don't have the option of using foreign keys.

Comment: So for the Course_Module Table you are saying include them two fields as primary kwys but not forigen keys?

Comment: You can use foreign keys. I just mentioned the fact that you might run into problems with foreign keys with MySQL in that it is not always supported.

Comment: From a (relational) data modelling standpoint, a table *without* a PK is meaningless. Duplicates could be present, but what would be their meaning? If there are two records in the course_module junction table would that mean that the module is part of the course *twice* ? And what would happen on deletion, should you delete both records, or just one ?

Comment: @wildplasser -- The question asked if you have to have a PK. The answer to that is no. Whether it is meaningful in this case is unlikely since it is highly improbable that you want to add a module to a course twice. It does allow for flexible (lazy) programming in that you can insert a record without concern that it might raise an error.